# Charles 4.2.8 cannot configure your proxy settings while it is on a read-only volume Mac OS Catalina

Tags: macos, proxy, macos-catalina

On macOS Catalina, i am getting the following issue while running Charles 4.2.8.

> Charles cannot configure your proxy settings while it is on a read-only volume. Perhaps you are running Charles from the disk image? If so, please copy Charles to the Applications folder and run it again. Otherwise please ensure that Charles is running on a volume that is read-write and try again.

Comment: Hi Nevin, welcome to Super User. When you find your own solution, you are encouraged to post it as an Answer post on your own Question, and then click the check-mark outline to Accept your own Answer. That way the question is marked as resolved and people can clearly see what the solution was.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Got the solution - Change the ownership & permission of the "charles resource folder".

```
 sudo chown -R root "/Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Resources"
 sudo chmod -R u+s "/Applications/Charles.app/Contents/Resources"
```